# R not identified after updating to Android v.21

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-appcompat

I have Eclipse Luna installed on my Mac and yesterday night I downloaded from the sdk manager the latest android sdk (v. 21 Android 5.0). Unfortunately after the update I got several errors that I tried to solve following the instructions in several posts here in Stack Overflow.
1. In java build path under Android Dependencies the jar file for Appcompact 7 was not found under the bin folder. I've read that this was due to the fact that I should have set 21 as the project target for the support library then clear and build the library project so that the jar file would be automatically created under the bin folder, but that didn't happened.
2. I added the jar file of the library under the bin folder manually. At this point instead of having the exclamation mark on the project name I have all the files under src folder marked with errors as the R file is not recognized anymore. I don't have any errors in any xml file, but still R resources are not found in the project.
3. Every time I try to change the target sdk for my project to 21 or 21 with google apis I get an error stating "Parsing Data for Google Inc.:Google APIs:21 failed Unsupported major.minor version 51.0". I've read that probably this is due to the jdk version installed on the computer so I updated it to the version 8 and changed the compiler in Eclipse to the 1.8 version. That didn't solve the problem so I got it back to 1.6.
4. In the problems tab I have the following errors:
- The import com.google.android.gms cannot be resolved;
- R cannot be resolved to a variable;
- the method initializePoolObject() of type DBObjectStructure must override a superclass method.

Do you have any idea of how to get to work again wthout any problems?

Comment: I have same problem too. If you find answer please post here.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I didn't find any solution, and I couldn't wait any longer so I was "forced" to migrate to Android Studio. Now it works like a charm, I just had to struggle a little bit with the gradle system. I hope I won't have any bad suprises at the next update I will have to launch. I kindly ask you the same thing to you... If you find a solution with Eclipse, please let me know it. Good luck!

Comment: I am having the same issue. But android studio runs very slow on my laptop. :( Every project with api 21 shows this error: "R not resolved to a variable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- > The import com.google.android.gms cannot be resolved

  **com.google.android.gms** comes from the **Play Services SDK**, which you attach to your application project as an Android library
  project.  Please check your environment to ensure that you have a
  valid copy of the Play Services library project and that your
  application project still points to it.

  **Install a new Play Services:**

  Follow the instruction from Google to install
  'google-play-services-lib' project.

  [This](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) is the documentation.
- > R cannot be resolved to a variable

  Make sure that your **compiling** and **target versions are set to
  21.** Its because the new AppCompat only compiles on 21.

  Right click the project and click **"Properties".** Then select **"Android"** from the tree on the  left. You can then select the target target version on the right.

  **Note:** Make sure your properties, classpath and project files are writable otherwise it won't work
- > The method initializePoolObject() of type DBObjectStructure must override a superclass method.

  You have to update your jdk version into **1.8** to overcome this
  error.Also change the java compiling version of your project into 1.8
  in eclipse.

Comment: I have the latest jdk but still having that error "R cannot be resolved to a variable" as soon I update targetSDK to 21 from 19.

Comment: "R cannot be resolved" error is not related to jdk. It is related to res folder of your project. check your PlayServices and AppCompat libraries are up to dated, and make sure your resource folder does not contains any error.

Comment: Also just try to create a new project in eclipse and try to compile it.

Comment: Actually, installing Java 1.7 worked for me (Mac Yosemite). I restarted Eclipse, rebuilt Google Play Services), then rebuilt my project... Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new project for Lollipop, Android Studio warned that java 7 is required. I know java 8 is not yet supported in Android, so that won't work, but I suggest you go with the latest update of java 7, perhaps the issue in Eclipse is the same, just the warning is missing.

Comment: I already use latest java 7 update and it is added to eclipse too.

Answer (score 0):

to fix the R not identified error migrate to android studio.  Version .8 should be sufficient evidence that the beta version is of release quality.

For eclipse delete the import myapp.R and then re-add them this has worked for me in the past.

Answer (score -1):

Try use other IDE like Andorid Studio or InteliJ IDE, maximum resolves your error.